# How to use action method of core module (observer.php) in my custom module controller.?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

As I am new to PHP as wel MAGENTO
I want to use **core sitemap controller action** in my own custom module.
 suggest me how.

```
  public function scheduledGenerateSitemaps($schedule)
  {
        $errors = array();

        // check if scheduled generation enabled
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_GENERATION_ENABLED)) {
            return;
        }

        $collection = Mage::getModel('sitemap/sitemap')->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Sitemap_Model_Mysql4_Sitemap_Collection */
        foreach ($collection as $sitemap) {
            /* @var $sitemap Mage_Sitemap_Model_Sitemap */

            try {
                $sitemap->generateXml();
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        if ($errors && Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ERROR_RECIPIENT)) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);

            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            /* @var $emailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'backend'))
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ERROR_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ERROR_IDENTITY),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_ERROR_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('warnings' => join("\n", $errors))
                );

            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
        }
  }
```

This I have to use in my IndexController.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call the function by its model ? Like :

```
Mage::getModel('sitemap/observer')->scheduledGenerateSitemaps()
```